# Unable to track memory leak in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-leaks

I have a realtime application RTMP based streaming application which if run, leaks memory. Unfortunately I can't run it through valgrind since it is a live application

Here are the issues
1. Application PID memory stays constant to 3.8% even after hours
2. Kernel memory through slabtop remains constant
3. In meminfo, I see available memory keeps reducing!

How do I know who is taking up this memory? I'm suspecting TCP buffer or something like that. Can someone pls help?

Comment: When I add up %MEM of top, it does not match with used memory

Comment: are you sure it's not just the [linux disk cache](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

Comment: Look at *all* values in memingo. Plot them over time and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for us to say where are you leaking with only the information provided.

If you can't use Valgrind, what I suggest is that you try to isolate various functionalities/modules of your program. Then, try to disable/enable those modules to see if there's is a leak or not when you disable/enable it.

For example, try to disable the networking module of your application, to see if it continues to leak or not. This way you can probably narrow the problem to one/various modules and not the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

I found the rootcause. Setting tcp memory in Linux to 32MB was causing the problem. Reset it to 87KB which is the default value in Centos 7.2

Not sure why setting it to high value should cause the issue